# Getting Facebook session when I start my Android app?

Tags: android

First, I have to login to a Facebook account in my app. However, when I quit my application and start mp application again, I still have to log in account facebook again without input

my password because my application has session already. Do I have to save my facebook session

in `SharedPreferance` if I want to make my application log in automatically when start again?

Answer (score 1):

As you dont want to login again and again to facebook in your application. You just have to save the `Access Token` in `SharedPreference` and thats all :).

Comment: Could I ask you something? When I log in into facebook, how many data that I have to concern about? Just like how can I get my facebook Id or why I have to save access token.

Comment: The graph api has method to get the username, email, id and for posting on wall you dont have to worry about it :). Once your token is saved, facebook recognize that the user has been logged in by AccessToken.